# Should you normalize outputs of a neural network for regression tasks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, normalization

I've made a CNN that takes a signal as input and outputs the parameters used in a simulation to create that signal. I've heard that for regression tasks [you don't normally normalize the outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604261/neural-networks-normalizing-output-data) to a neural network. But the variables the model is trying to predict have very different standard deviations, like one variable is always in the range of [1x10^-20, 1x10-24] while another is almost always in the range of [8, 16]. My question is since all loss functions first take the difference between the target and actual output values and this difference would naturally scale with the std of that output variable wouldn't loss of the network mostly dependent on the accuracy of the output variables with large stds and not ones with small stds? Also would unnormalized output hinder the training process since the network can get low loss for an output variable with very low std by just guessing values close to its mean?

If this is the case why can't I find much on the internet talking about or suggesting to normalize outputs? It seems really important for getting reliable loss values.

Comment: You don't care how close you get the parameters. You care how closely you model. The solution is a multidimensional thing. You are approximating it by a function of the parameters. You get an approximation per point in parameter space. You don't care about the values of the parameters, ie the scale on the axes; you just want to  investigate the relevant range of values for each. But feedback is based on output vs input. Normalization is un-scaling. You could *separately* normalize input/output dimensions for relative accuracy in determining difference. (Surely an intro says this in equations?)

Comment: Sorry let me clarify when I say "parameters" I don't mean weights I mean the parameters used in a simulation to create the input signal, they are the values the model is trying to predict. Also I assumed I could normalize the input/output dimensions that but a found more than one place on the web that said you don't need to for regression problems ([here is another link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-right-way-of-normalizing-neural-network-inputs-outputs-while-making-predictions)). I'm asking if that's true and if so why?

Comment: I mean what you mean. You can only measure phenotypes (signals) but you want to guess genotypes (parameters). You have an oracle (NN) with memory (weights) & input (a possibly transformed signal) outputting guesses (transformable to parameter values)  We normalize values per what the oracle can do. For output, to map the oracle's ranges to the problem ranges, and maybe to compensate for how the oracle balances them. For input, so the oracle can handle it, and maybe to compensate for how the oracle will balance its dimensions. You have to analyze/design on a per-case basis. (More later.)

Comment: Hmm ok so your saying that output normalization is normal then? Thanks for the help, also interesting analogy I don't think I've heard someone call a neural network an oracle before haha.

Comment: But what normalizations do you expect to do? You compare the associated signal for outputs to another signal; outputs are otherwise irrelevant. Also, if your NN can't handle extreme values or extremly different values on output, what do you expect to do about it? Maybe you can normalize input to keep *it and its parameters in range*; but in general you have to *make a NN that can handle the extremes*. So at this point, please clarify what your problem is in terms of your NN, function from parmameters to signals, NN i/o normalizations & learning iterations.

Comment: PS Have you googled, say, 'neural network learning normalization input output'? Eg hit [Data normalization and standardization in neural networks
](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7757} & its many links.

Comment: The outputs aren't just for comparison and otherwise irrelevant they have real world meaning. They are the distance, total mass and mass ratio of the black hole binaries that create the gravitational wave signals we are analyzing. Also, just to clarify, the only "extreme values" I think will mess with the network are those will wildly different standard deviations, extreme means aren't an issue.

Comment: What I would plan to do about it is find the stds of the output variables over values I can expect to see then divide all the target values by those stds before training. Then I'll multiply the output by those stds when actually using the network. That way the loss for the network will depend on all output variable errors evenly. Also like I said earlier an output variable will a small std will get low error if the network guesses that variable's mean all the time which could allow the network to not actually learn how to predict that variable. This would be avoided too by what I plan to do.

Comment: I meant other than for creating a new signal, they are irrelevant to the learning. Of course they are the desired output of the overall process. Although you may have to stop when they and/or their new signal and/or the weights don't change enough.

Comment: So are you saying that the second concern I mentioned in my last comment wouldn't happen because the output values are "irrelevant to the learning process"?

Comment: I'm raising general issues that might suggest problems to you but per previous comments, but I am not clear on what you are doing. Also your language is unclear. Eg "target values"--parameters that generated an original signal, or the various original signals, or the sequence of signals generated by preceding parameters output, or the last input signal's generating or NN-guessed parameters, or what? How exactly are you "actually using the network"/"training"? Compare to my talk of functions from inputs to outputs. Again: Edit your question to explain/diagram how you map, normalize & iterate.

Comment: I've heard many different names used for some of the things I'm trying to describe like "target values", what I mean is the values that the network needs to guess given an input signal, which are also the params used to generate that signal. I honestly have had trouble understanding you myself. I'll try to explain one more time what I'm doing though: I've found the standard deviations of the output variables of the network and divided the "target values" in the training data by their corresponding stds.

Comment: Once the training is done I add a "lambda layer" (a layer that just applies an arbitrary function with no trainable weights) that "de-normalizes" the output of the network so it is usable. I ended up actually running a test though to check myself if normalization

Comment: was necessary and the results I got strongly suggested it was. Without normalization the network would have very high loss because of one output variable with large std but got 100% accuracy almost immediately which shouldn't be possible. The version with normalization had much more reasonable loss and accuracy values.